# is there range map in c++?

Tags: c++, stl, unordered-map

in c++, `unordered_map` and `map` are good tools to search key from a map.

i can build a map, which a key is date and value is double (or my self-defined struct).

but i want a range map, which means the key is a range, for example:

```
#inlcude <map>
m[20190101] =3;
m[20201201] = 4.
cout << m[20200101]; // i want this can return me 3. because 20200101 is
// lower-close to 20190101
```

how can i implement this?

Comment: There's the problem that a map's key should identify one and only one element. But if you're fine with the ranges in your map never overlapping, a custom comparer should do the trick, though it may be dificult to implement.

Comment: Not in the standard library. You would have to code this up yourself. But how would you use such a map? Can you provide the code you would expect to use to set values and later retrieve them?

Comment: @Galik please see the updates, i am designing a stock trading system, which i need a tiny database to save trading fee for each stock, the fee is seldom changed(in 10 years, it only changed less than 10 times), which means build a [date, value] is very wasteful, and i need this fast, because i need to search it a lot.

Comment: Using a map for this is pointless.  Store a sorted array of dates paired with the value, then use a binary search to find your date with `std::lower_bound` or similar.

Comment: @paddy: That is still a map concept, though not implemented via the `std::map` data structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::map` stores the data in a binary tree, so you can easily find the closest key greater than/greater than or equal to a value with the `upper_bound` and `lower_bound` methods

- `m.lower_bound(k)`:  returns an iterator pointing to the first element with key not less than k, or m.end() if such an element is not found.
- `m.upper_bound(k)`:  returns an iterator pointing to the first element with key greater than k, or m.end() if such an element is not found.

You can then decrement the iterator (if it is not equal to `begin()`) to find the next smaller element.

So for your example:

```
auto it = m.upper_bound(20200101);
if (it != m.begin())
    std::cout << *--it;
else
    std::cout << "no key <= 20200101";
```

Comment: great, thanks Chris. so i think this will be slow than: store all dates values into map one by one. store all waste space, but search will be O(1), this method saved space, but lower_boud is a O(log(n)) operation, which is a little slower

Comment: It depends on the data, but wasting a lot of space is likely to end up slower, due to caching effects.  Your best bet is to profile different approaches to see which is fastest (and if the speed difference even matters or is dominated by other things, such as I/O)

Answer (score 2):

Way back in 2013/2014, I created a `range_map` container class template modeled on the container class templates of the C++ standard library. Each item of the `range_map` is stored in a class template called `range_map_item`, which has 3 fields: the left bound, the right bound, and the stored item. (FYI, everything is in the `beneficii` namespace.) It to a large extent works like `std::map`, but does not wrap around it. I created my own rb-tree to manage its contents.

The way the ranges work are as follows. Each key covers a range like so:

[left bound, right bound)

Meaning, the left bound is part of the range, but the right bound is not.

Ranges cannot imperfectly overlap, that is you can't have a 2 ranges where this is true:

left1 < left2 < right1 < right2

If 2 ranges do overlap, one must be entirely a subrange of the other.

The iterators go through by the range bounds, rather than the ranges themselves. It can tell you if it's currently pointing to a left bound or a right bound.

I've done a fair amount of testing with it. I've been able to create BMP files created by iterating through a range_map with random ranges placed in it and displaying the result. It seems to basically work, but I can't guarantee it will 100% and I haven't touched it in over 5 years.

There's no documentation with it, but the functions required to interact with it work similarly to their C++ standard library container counterparts. I would use `emplace()` most often. You can just pass the left bound, the right bound, and the item to it. (FYI, the "encaps" parameter is for whether you want to encapsulate preexisting items if those happen to be subranges of the item you want to enter/create.) You can also use piecewise construction on `emplace()` as well. (Thanks to a blog I found online that taught me how to set that up.)

Here is a link to the library. You should keep it in the "beneficii" subfolder, and just place that subfolder in your include directory or project directory or whatever. Wherever the compiler can search for include files. The library is header-only, so there are no linking issues.

Here is a link to the download:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SlBvIqnXwfJfsWv6yJsTm9SfutVok21U/view?usp=sharing